# How to use QStackedWidget in GUI?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qt-creator, qstackedwidget

I am new to Qt and am have to make a GUI having multiple windows for this I found `QStackedWidget` class using Qt designer tools.

I added `QStackedWidget` using add new->Qt designer form class->Qstackwidget

after that I created an object of this class in my main window

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include<stackedwidget.h>

namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow {
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    StackedWidget *stk; };

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

then i tried to display StackedWidget by:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    stk = new StackedWidget(this);
    stk->show();
}
```

But stackwidget is not opening .

Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong and how to implement `QStackedWidget` GUI using designer tools?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [QStackedWidget](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qstackedwidget.html#details) class provides a stack of widgets where only one widget is visible at a time.

You are new to Qt so I suggest you to using Qt Designer: [image: Image Example]

You can drag&drop StackedWidget to your form, customize it then use arrows to go to the next page and work on it too.

StackedWidget is like a vector you can access them via indexes.

```
ui->stackedWidget->setCurrentIndex(1);
```